# With a camera inside a cylinder i want to detect circles in the walls. What should be the dimensions of the ellipses in the wall of the cylinder?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, camera, computer-vision, transformation

Objectifying the question, I have a camera inside a cylinder (in the center of the cylinder), I want the walls of the cylinder to have a grid of circles, so in the 2D plane (rectangle) I must have some ellipses. What I want to know is what dimensions should be the ellipses in the plane?

Cylinder lenght - l
Cylinder radius - r

Circle inside the cylinder, radius - r1

I was thinking to do a ellipse with radius r1 and r2>r1. The radius r2 should be obtained according to the distance between the circle and the camera. Do you have any different ideas?

The image below is the camera perspective of a simple grid with circles of radius r1. The camera see ellipses, where the radius of the r2 is inferior of radius r1 and is becoming smaller with the distance to the camera.

[image]

Comment: In which programming language?

Comment: I use matlab. But I only want to know how to do it, so it can be in any programming language (I can adapt to matlab after knowing the method). I'm not sure if this is a linear transformation.

Comment: Ahem, you do realize that the black blotches in that image above are not elliptical, right? More generally, drawing a circle onto a plane, and then rolling the plane into a cylinder, deforms the circle into a banana, and projecting bananas into cameras yields even tastier bananas :-)

Comment: I noticed that. It's not a perfect ellipse (you can call it a banana form). What I should draw in the plane to appear a circle in the cylinder? I thought doing some ellipses in the plane would make the "banana" form in the cylinder look more like a circle. Maybe there is some kind of transformation to do this... I don't have much experience in this kind of camera/images transformations. I want to know the theory behind this to be able to implement a algorithm to do circles in the cylinder walls. Can you help me? Thank you for your comment

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your exact question but I see this problem in a simpler manner. Just detect all the contours minus one (the last big circle ie opening of cylinder). Is there any problem in this method or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, but you didn't understand my question. I don't want to detect the circles. I want to do a program which can give me a 2D figure (i think it's similar to a ellipse) that I can put in the cylinder and with the camera inside I could see a perfect circle. So I want a projection transform which allow me to see circles with the camera in the middle of the cylinder.

Comment: I already found a answer by myself to this question, I haven't had time to publish in here yet, but I will. In my answer I consider the pin hole camera transform. It worked perfectly. Thanks for the help you guys. Give me one more week and I will publish in here the answer